# Is there anyway to UPDATE a series of columns on a row with a composite type record/row?

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-9.5, row, composite-types

Take a table `foo`,

```
CREATE TABLE foo(a,b,c,d)
AS VALUES
  (1,2,3,4);
```

I can insert into `foo` with a row type..

```
INSERT INTO foo
  SELECT (foo).*
  FROM foo;

INSERT INTO foo
  SELECT (v).*
  FROM ( VALUES (42,42,42,42) )
    AS v;
```

But I can't update foo with a row type.

```
-- fails
UPDATE foo SET (a,b,c,d) = (
  SELECT ROW(1,2,3,4)
).*;

-- also fails.
UPDATE foo SET (a,b,c,d) = (SELECT (1,2,3,4));
ERROR:  number of columns does not match number of values
LINE 1: UPDATE foo SET (a,b,c,d) = (SELECT (1,2,3,4));
```

Is there any syntax to update an entire row with a composite type. The really weird thing is that this works in a trigger with `NEW`, and I'm trying to write the same code without a trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
  BEGIN
    NEW=(42,42,42,42);
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE;

CREATE TRIGGER ok
  BEFORE UPDATE ON foo
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo();

-- The NEW row in trigger gets updated with (42,42,42,42)
-- the UPDATE succeeds; all rows (42,42,42,42)
UPDATE foo
  SET (a,b,c,d) = (1,2,3,4);
```

You can see here that we can update the row object inside the procedure, and change the update. However, we can't do that in the `UPDATE` ddl? I would expect the RECORD produced by the same name of the table to work the same way.

```
-- Such as this,
UPDATE foo
  SET foo = (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: The trigger works, ok. I meant there is no code there that has `update .. set (list_of_columns) = row(..);`

Comment: When you update NEW, you're updating a *record* (per the docs). That's what I want to do. I want to update a record with `UPDATE` -- the record that represents the current row typed to the table, that has the same name. I just don't know if I'm not getting the syntax right or if it's impossible.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you want. I think it's not possible, yet. There was a discussion at pgsql-hackers list. See https://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org/msg298265.html

Comment: Yes, no response to that patch -- guess it never got committed? =( Here is another one https://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org/msg237578.html If you want to make an answer with those links I'll upvote and mark as accepted. Seems the answer is "it's not possible, yet"

Answer (score 1):

There are actually lots of posts regarding this..

- [Support UPDATE table SET(*)=...](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAOeZVif44gNx-uqE=qNm5FDu+LfSjK94jSm1goHMH2Fc3u1FpQ@mail.gmail.com#CAOeZVif44gNx-uqE=qNm5FDu+LfSjK94jSm1goHMH2Fc3u1FpQ@mail.gmail.com)
- [WIP patch for multiple column assignment in UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20930.1402931841@sss.pgh.pa.us)
- [Supporting multiple column assignment in UPDATE (9.5 project)](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1783.1399054541@sss.pgh.pa.us)
- [Better handling of UPDATE multiple-assignment row expressions](https://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org/msg298265.html)

However, according to [/u/pstef, one of these is committed, and this syntax now works **on HEAD**](https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/70ai2t/is_there_anyway_to_update_a_series_of_columns_on/), though @ypercubeᵀᴹ reports it does not work on 9.6.5

```
UPDATE foo SET (a,b,c,d) = ROW(10,9,8,7);
```

The [docs don't say much about this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-update.html)

> According to the standard, the source value for a parenthesized sub-list of target column names can be any row-valued expression yielding the correct number of columns. **PostgreSQL only allows the source value to be a row constructor or a sub-SELECT. **An individual column's updated value can be specified as DEFAULT in the row-constructor case, but not inside a sub-SELECT.

But you can also see at the [syntax for UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-update.html)

```
   ( column_name [, ...] ) = [ ROW ] ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) |
```

Comment: Regarding link 2: *"It works for me **on HEAD**"* I suppose that means it still works only in beta. I don't see it working in 9.6.5.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ good note, updated. I don't have a running 9.6.

Answer (score 0):

How about (server 9.5.7) ...

```
create table foo(a,b,c,d)
as values
  (1,2,3,4)
, (4,5,6,7)
, (8,9,0,null);

postgres=# select * from foo;
 a | b | c | d 
---+---+---+---
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
 4 | 5 | 6 | 7
 8 | 9 | 0 |  
(3 rows)


update foo
set (a,b,c,d) = ( 
  select (v).*
  from ( values (42,42,42,42) ) as v 
) ;

postgres=# select * from foo;
 a  | b  | c  | d  
----+----+----+----
 42 | 42 | 42 | 42
 42 | 42 | 42 | 42
 42 | 42 | 42 | 42
(3 rows)
```

Dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=71ba7fecb09543febd783d10e257dc20).

Or, indeed (without trigger):

```
postgres=# update foo
postgres-# set (a,b,c,d) = (11,22,33,44) ;
UPDATE 3
postgres=# select * from foo;
 a  | b  | c  | d  
----+----+----+----
 11 | 22 | 33 | 44
 11 | 22 | 33 | 44
 11 | 22 | 33 | 44
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I can see how this looks really close to what I'm looking but it's not at all it. I almost want to up vote for the attempt. Row-objects can be converted to and from other types. For instance, `SELECT new.*
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_populate_record(
  null::foo,
  to_jsonb(foo)
    || jsonb_build_object(CASE WHEN random() > 0.5 THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END, 7)
    || jsonb_build_object(CASE WHEN random() > 0.5 THEN 'c' ELSE 'd' END, 13)
) AS new;` That's complex, but that's what I'm trying to do with the row objects. Now try to update the original row with it, and do it all inline.

Comment: When using your SELECT to create a new table from "foo", the UPDATEs work the same as before.  See http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=590778490b2df0b21e4a7ebc45b078c4

Comment: I know what you are on about, though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (in versions 9.5 and 9.6) but I'm not if it will solve your issue.

- convert the row into type `foo`:

  ```
  row(1,2,3,4)::foo
  ```
- expand it into columns:

  ```
  select ( ).*
  ```

The whole code:

```
update foo set (a,b,c,d) = (select (row(1,2,3,4)::foo).*) ;
```